# create dynamic menu MVC php

Tags: php, optimization, model-view-controller

I'm working on an MVC php project (CMS workpress Like) and I found myself stuck when I tried to create a menu from a list of pages titles stored in my BD.

To give you more details, 
I'm using templating for my Views

Here is my template including my View :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?php echo $page_title ?></title>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $page_description ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/setupmywebsite/Public/css/style_front.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header></header>
    <section>
        <?php include $this->view; ?>
        <!--View front-->
```

$this->view represent the view.php file with html and css.

The problem is that I want to insert a dynamic < nav > with < a > and the list of pages_titles from my DB.

I can't query here because its not right, and I can't do it in all the front_controllers because its gonna be redondant as hell.

I had an idea of defining global PATHS (1 to 5 ) and directly use them in the href.

Do someone have have an idea of how it is working in other known websites (wordpress drupal etc).

Thanks you very much !!

Comment: which MVC framework are you using??

Comment: i'm doing my own MVC

Comment: https://youtu.be/Z7vXAI0z5I8

Answer (score 0):

Actually I managed to do it in a nice way. I created a helpers get_menu(), getting page titles from Database and returning an Array of Titles

```
static function get_menu()
    {
            $menu = new Pages();

            $menus =$menu->getAllBy($search = [[]]);
            return $menus; //array
    }
```

I used a foreach in the view template. I didn't find any better solution ;).